# Making Back Ground Image Full Width

Tags: css, wordpress, fullscreen, markup

When you open www.nomadicmatt.com on mobile devices the first image you see is his big bold background image. I am trying to replicate the same thing on my site www.rosstheexplorer.com. The header image looks too small on mobile devices hence why I am exploring having a background image.

To achieve this I was told the following

You must change your markup. Change your

```
<img class="custom-header">
```

to

```
<div class="custom-header">
```

and set container background property:

```
.custom-header { 
   background: url(path_to_image) no-repeat; 
   background-size: cover; 
}
```

I was also told, you can set style on div like this

```
<div style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>); background-size: cover;">
```

I tried inserting the following code into additional CSS

```
 <div style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>); background-size: cover;"> </div> And 

.custom-header { background: url("rosstheexplorer.com/cover-photo-1/") no-repeat; background-size: cover; }
```

I got the error message

> Markup is not allowed in CSS.

I tried each line individually and there was an issue with both lines
Where do you alter the markup? Or is there another solution?

I have now been told I may have to make the changes in the index.php file, this is the code for my index.php file

```
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">



        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">



        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php penscratch_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->



</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: would it not be `<?php echo header_image(); ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have tried putting **html code in css file**. That is you inserted

```
<div style="background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>); background-size: cover;"> </div>
```

in your **css** file. This is not going to work. You need to change the markup in **html file** that might be generated using php so you actually might need to put this markup in **index.php** or something.

Comment: I have just put my index.php code in my original comment

Comment: Is this the line you are referring to - <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="" class="custom-header"> Would I need to change it to <div src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="" class="custom-header"> –

Comment: @RossSymonds You'd need to remove `src` from div and add inline style to it. In that inline style you can mention the background url so that you could make it dynamic with php.

Comment: @RossSymonds As I see in your actual post you seem to be using some wordpress template. So you'd actually need to change the specific template file. I don't know much about php so may be someone else could help you aout there.

Answer (score 0):

Your have given padding and margin that is creating issue. Please look into attached image
[image: banner]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately that solution stretches all the content. I just want to enlarge my logo.

Comment: put image in another div on top of  div where id:page.Image attached